# How to instantly delete posts/pages permanently?

Tags: customization

For development purpose I need to constantly fill and unfill a Wordpress instance with dummy content. Deleting everything in two steps is quite annoying, so I'm wondering if there's a way to cut the long way around to trash when deleting posts. Please help.

Comment: There is also a plugin available to delete instantly from the dashboard that works for all post types.
See: https://wordpress.org/plugins/force-delete-posts/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Considering this site is WordPress Development, I'm assuming you would like to know how to (force) delete posts programmatically.

```
wp_delete_post(257, true); // `true` indicated you would like to force delete (skip trash)
```

[More on `wp_delete_post()` function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_delete_post)

Answer (score 4):

You can set a time interval for automatically empty trash:

In your wp-config.php put:

```
define('EMPTY_TRASH_DAYS', 1 ); //Integer is the amount of days
```

**EDIT:** To disable trash set the number of days to zero (http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php)

Hope it helps!

Comment: To make instant deletion work this has to be set to `0`.

Comment: @ialocin - Setting `define( 'EMPTY_TRASH_DAYS', 0 );` only turns off automatic deletion. Items then stay in trash forever if not deleted manually.

Comment: @koivo read: http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Empty_Trash and/or http://codex.wordpress.org/Trash_status#Default_Days_before_Permanently_Deleted

Comment: @koivo "To disable trash set the number of days to zero. Note that WordPress will not ask for confirmation when someone clicks on "Delete Permanently"." It is from codex.

Comment: @ialocin - Please try it yourself. It only switches off automatic deletion. I've read the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Using WP-CLI this can be achieved pretty easily combining [`wp post list`](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/post/list/) and [`wp post delete`](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/post/delete/) with the `--force` option to skip the trash bin like so:

```
# Delete all posts skipping trash
$ wp post delete $(wp post list --post_type='post' --format=ids) --force
```

---

Other examples:

> ```
> # Delete post skipping trash
> $ wp post delete 123 --force
> Success: Deleted post 123.
>
> # Delete all pages
> $ wp post delete $(wp post list --post_type='page' --format=ids)
> Success: Trashed post 1164.
> Success: Trashed post 1186.
>
> # Delete all posts in the trash
> $ wp post delete $(wp post list --post_status=trash --format=ids)
> Success: Deleted post 1268.
> Success: Deleted post 1294.
> ```

Comment: This doesn't work if you have WPML

Comment: @FooBar – Why ?